# How to create a php variable using Wordpress the_title() function

Tags: php, functions

I want to create a php variable which will use the `the_title` function:

So if the title of the post is "Style" the variable will name will be `$style` and if the post title is "Dog" the variable name will be `$Dog`.

Is it possible?

I tried `${the_title()};`

But it echoes the title.

My goal is to use at as a dynamic variable inside a each loop and increase it's number every time it gets the same title. so for example for each post with unique title it will be set to '1' but if a title repeats a second time it will be set to '2' and so on...

Comment: "are you sure you want to do this?" wouldn't it be better to expand the title into an array to use that eg. `$titlewords = explode(" ", get_the_title());`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Aren't you afraid that your new variable will overwrite some other crucial variables like for instance `post` or what will happen if the title will include characters like space or an quote?

Comment: I can add a prefix like "wefij_the_title" and i can handle the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function echoes the title, unless you set the third parameter to false (default true). So you start with this;

```
$title = the_title ('','',false);
```

Now, `$title` may contain all kinds of characters that cannot be used in PHP variable names, so we need some sanitization:

```
$title = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\_]/', '', $title); // Removes special chars except underscore.
```

Then you use [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to turn the content of `$title` into a variable name:

```
$$title = 'something';
```

So, if `the_title` gives the value "hello world", the `$title` variable after sanitizing has the value "helloworld" and `$helloworld` has the value "something".

Comment: why is it that if i just set `$title = the_title('','',false);` and the `echo $$title;` it echoes the the title? isn't it suppose to be empty until is set it to something? my goal is to set it to increasing number with each loop, so i don't need to set it to '0' which will reset it... and still be different for every post... I have updated the question to explain it.

Comment: You would need to echo ${$title}

Comment: For your purpose this approach is quite complicated. You could just store every title in an array and then use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to see how often it has been used before. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235186/how-to-check-if-an-array-has-a-value-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

> so for example for each post with unique title it will be set to '1' but if a title repeats a second time it will be set to '2' and so on...

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) after casting titles in an array. Use [`the_title_attribute()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) with a `false` argument to get an [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) & tag-stripped title. Be mindful of regex used with `preg_replace` or you can end up with false matches. After setting `array_count_values()`, a foreach loop using `as $key => $value` can use [complex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to create variable names based on `$key` (aka `post_title`): `${'_'. $key} = $value`.

---

Once you have all post objects, loop through them.

### Getting title

You can use `the_title_attribute()`, since it runs title through `esc_attr();`

```
$title_cleaned = the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false, );  
//OR: $post->post_title for raw from object
```

---

Side Note: Alternatively, from the object you can get the raw title from `$post->post_title`

```
foreach ($posts as $post) { 
    $title_cleaned = esc_attr( $post->post_title ) 
    }
```

---

### Trim, sanitize, preg_replace

remove any leading or ending extra spaces and force type to string

```
$title_cleaned = (string) trim( $post );
```

remove any non-alphanumeric space, leaving spaces

```
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', '', $title_cleaned );
```

change spaces to underscores

```
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '_', $title_cleaned );
```

cast value to array

```
$array_of_titles[] = $title_cleaned;
```

// loop end

---

### Get count

Use `array_count_values()` to cast `key => values` of `post_title => count`

```
$counted_array = array_count_values( $array_of_titles );
```

The value of `$counted_array` will be something like:

```
Array (
    [ Style ] => 3
    [ Dog ] => 1
    )
```

---

### Setting ${'_'. $key} = $value

Set keys to variable names, adding an underscore to avoid numbers starting variable name

```
foreach( $counted_array as $key => $value ) {
    ${'_'. $key} = (int) $value;
  }
```

### Example of all the above together:

```
foreach ($posts as $post ) {
    $title_cleaned = the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false, );  
    $title_cleaned = (string) trim( $title_cleaned );
    $title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', '', $title_cleaned );
    $title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '_', $title_cleaned );
    $array_of_titles[] = $title_cleaned;
}

$counted_array = array_count_values( $array_of_titles );

foreach( $counted_array as $key => $value ) {
    ${'_'. $key} = (int) $value;
  }
```

---

### Example mockup

This php file can be used outside WP to see what I mean regarding the title to regex stuff.

```
<?php
//using array below as a mock response of titles after passing through esc_attr
$faux_the_title_attribute = array( ' My Styles &amp Colors ', 'My Style&#039s Colors', 'My Styles: Colors', 'My Styles: Colors', 'My Styles: Colors' );
foreach ($faux_the_title_attribute as $pt ) {
    //$title_cleaned = the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false, );
    $title_cleaned = (string) trim( $pt );
    $title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', '', $title_cleaned );
    $title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '_', $title_cleaned );
    //My Styles & Colors = My_Styles_amp_Colors

    $array_of_titles[] = $title_cleaned; 

}

$counted_array = array_count_values( $array_of_titles );

foreach( $counted_array as $key => $value ) {
    // ${'_'. $key} = $key . '_' . $value;
    //becomes $_My_Styles_amp_Colors = _My_Styles_amp_Colors_3;
    ${'_'. $key} = (int) $value;
    //becomes $_My_Styles_Colors = 3;
}

printf( $_My_Styles_amp_Colors );

?>
```

---

### A note on regex, post title strings to `${$title}`, and potential issues

You would need to prepend these in the event of a `post_title` beginning with a numerical, since [php variables must begin with a letter or underscore](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Depending on how you are getting the titles, `get_title()` as called by `the_title()`, or the object from `get_post` may not have filters applied.

While a regex like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*` will remove all non alphanumeric, without `esc_attr()` to `htmlencode` them first (i.e. with a `get_post()` using default `raw` filter), the returned strings *"My Styles & Colors"*,  *"My Style's Colors"*, or *"My Styles: Colors"* would all be `MyStylesColors` after the `preg_replace`.

However after `esc_attr()`:

```
My Styles & Colors = My Styles &amp Colors
My Style's Colors  = My Style&#039s Colors 
My Styles: Colors  = My Styles: Colors
```

After `esc_attr()` and regex `preg_replace`:

```
My Styles & Colors = MyStylesampColors
My Style's Colors  = MyStyle039sColors 
My Styles: Colors  = MyStylesColors
```

However, removing the whitespace in the expression (by not including it, i.e. `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*`), causes the following possible issues:

```
My Styles & le Colors  = MyStylesampleColors
My Style sample Colors = MyStylesampleColors
```

Adding whitespace to approved regex, and using second `preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $string);` to swap whitespace to underscores:

```
$title_cleaned = (string) the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false );
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $title_cleaned );
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '_', $title_cleaned );
//My Styles & Colors = My_Styles_amp_Colors
```

But that will convert opening or closing whitespaces to underscores, so php's `trim()` can handle those before any `preg_replace`.

None of this enforces the start of the variable name be a letter or underscore (numbers being invalid to start php variables).

So a post title:

```
3 Best Styles = 3BestStyles = $3BestStyles
```

You could validate against `^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$`, or prefix everything with an underscore.
So continuing from above `$title_cleaned` example:

```
$title_cleaned = the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false, );  
$title_cleaned = (string) trim( $title_cleaned );
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', '', $title_cleaned );
$title_cleaned = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '_', $title_cleaned );
$array_of_titles[] = $title_cleaned;
```

---

There could be other issues not taken into consideration here, too.

Personally, if just needing to know those counts and be able to compare, order, etc., I would stop at the step with `$counted_array = array_count_values( $array_of_titles );` and forgo the dynamic variable bit. IMO, of course.